# Histogram with shuffled x-axis

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a list `objects` which contains numbers. I tried to plot a histogram with this list as shown below.

```
plt.hist(objects, bins=50, range=[1, 25])
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Data')
```

and this results in the below plot. Why does this plot shuffle numbers on x-axis? (there are 1 numbers between 1 and 2 and the goes between 2 and 3 on x-axis)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, can you provide `objects` data values?

Comment: It is a list with size 18000 and contains numbers in the range from 0-50(repeated). I cannot upload the whole list here sorry!

Comment: If your objects are integer numbers, you should really be extremely careful using a continuous histogram for discrete data.  The bin boundaries need to be nicely in between the numbers. You can use e.g. `plt.hist(numerical_objects, bins=np.arange(-0.5, 51, 1))` to set such bin boundaries.  Or you can use seaborn's `sns.histplot(numerical_objects, discrete=True)` or `sns.countplot(numerical_objects)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `type` of the elements within `objects`: they could be `str` and you want them to be `int` of `float`.
If I use a random generated list of **strings** with:

```
objects = [str(n) for n in np.random.randint(0, 50, 1000)]

# ['38', '28', '14', '42', '7', '20', '38', '18', ...
```

and I try to plot the histogram of this list through the code you provided, I get this plot:

[image]

where the x axis is not ordered because matplotlib sees your values as strings, not as numbers.
So you need to convert them to number before plotting, for example with:

```
objects = [float(n) for n in objects]

# [38.0, 28.0, 14.0, 42.0, 7.0, 20.0, 38.0, 18.0, ...
```

After the conversion to number type, the histogram looks like this:

[image]